# How can I insert results of a query into a model in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can do this:

```
insert ignore into contacts 
(email, name)
SELECT email_address as email, full_name as name 
FROM contacts a 
right join contact_updates b on b.email_address=a.email
where a.id is null and b.license_status = 20
```

in Laravel?

I've tried this:

```
  $newContacts = Contact::rightJoin('contact_updates', 'contacts.email', '=', 'contact_updates.email_address')
    ->whereNull('contacts.id')
    ->where('contact_updates.license_status', 20)
    ->get(['name', 'email']);

  Contact::insertOrIgnore($newContacts);
```

, but laravel expects and array, not an object for insertOrIgnore.

Comment: try `Contact::insertOrIgnore($newContacts->toArray())`

Comment: If you have functional single-purpose SQL, I would just run it the way it is. \DB::statement($query);

Comment: That was my last option, but wanted to see if there is an 'eloquent' way to do it. "Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to avoid creating SQL injection vulnerabilities."

Comment: looks like `Contact::insertOrIgnore($newContacts->toArray())` only inserts one record, but not the whole object of records found.